# Send screenshot by email Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

I've asked a similar question before but I figured it out myself. But I now have a new problem, my device updated to android 8.0 and now email intent is not working. I don't want to downgrade my device if possible.

```
private void sendScreen() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".png";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        File filelocation = new File(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA  + mPath);
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filelocation);
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        // set the type to 'email'
        emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        String to[] = {"Enter your email address"};
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        // the attachment
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
        // the mail subject
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Journey : " + now );
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Select your preferred email app.."));


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my code which worked perfectly on android 7.0. The code takes a screenshot, time stamps it, saves it to the local storage and then attached it to an email app of the users choice. Anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This is my code which worked perfectly on android 7.0

It should have crashed with a `FileUriExposedException`.

> now email intent is not working

You did not explain what "is not working" means. I am going to guess that you are crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. A `file` `Uri` — whether via `Uri.fromFile()` or your `Uri.parse("file://"+...)` approach — is not usable on Android 7.0+ by default. [Switch to using `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: No not crashing for me, it will not take a screenshot or open email intent. Ok I will try them